# WPF Datepicker - SelectedDate just date and not time

Tags: c#, wpf, date, datepicker

I know this may be a duplicate but using the .NET framework I can't seem to get the date and not the time for a WPF DatePicker.

I have this:

```
DatePicker.SelectedDate.Value.Date
```

I believed using the "Date" property would only return the date, but it returns the time "12:00:00" as well.

I read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.date so I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

I'm sure it's something silly as always, but with no helpful eye with me to tell me, I thought I resort to SO!

Comment: DatePicker.SelectedDate.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`DatePicker.SelectedDate.Value.Date` is a `DateTime` Nullable property. So any `DateTime` Property has the date and time section. but in this case it is not fill with the correct value and it will gives you the default value. if you want to get the date only use following code,

```
DatePicker.SelectedDate.Value.Date.ToShortDateString()
```

Comment: This line will return the date and time (12:00:00 AM) .

Comment: @abdou_dev: Note the `.Date` part here that is skipping the time part and return only the date. check the values on  `DateTim.Today` and `DateTime.Now` and `DateTime.Now.Date`

Comment: In my case , no it return also the time part ( default time part 12:00:00 AM )

Answer (score 3):

`SelectedDate` property is of type `Nullable<DateTime>` it gives you the date however the time is reset as `12:00:00 midnight (00:00:00)`

see more on [DatePicker.SelectedDate Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker.selecteddate(v=vs.110).aspx)

from [MSDN: DateTime.Date Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The value of the Kind property of the returned DateTime value is the same as that of the current instance.
>   Because the DateTime type represents both dates and times in a single type, it is important to avoid misinterpreting a date returned by the Date property as a date and time. For more information, see "Saving and Restoring DateTime Values" in the DateTime topic.

Answer (score 2):

While selecting the date from the datepicker in you code you can do following:

```
    DateTime from = From_Date_Picker.SelectedDate.Value.Date
```

Answer (score 1):

> The following example uses the Date property to extract the date component of a DateTime value with its time component set to zero (or 0:00:00, or midnight). It also illustrates that, depending on the format string used when displaying the DateTime value, the time component can continue to appear in formatted output.

That says that depending on the Format (in this case the DatePicker i think) the Time component can appear. Like in your link, the Output is 12:00 AM

So Check the Format / properties of the DatePicker.

Answer (score 1):

in your code, you can do the following:

```
string shortDate = datePicker.SelectedDate.Value.ToShortDateString();
```

or, if you'd like to specify the format of the date:

```
string formatDate = datePicker.SelectedDate.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Here datePicker is object of DatePicker WPF

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure your Windows regional settings are set to a 24hr clock.  I'm guessing its returning 12AM